# Custom Validation Rule with nested arrays

Tags: validation, laravel

I'm trying to do an custom validation rule to test if the selling prices are greater than the purchasing prices. But the products are into a nested array. When run the debugger I can see the value of the first param correctly ('price_purchase') with his value but the second param ($price_sell) has the "raw data" 'products.*.purchase_price' instead the corresponding value. How can do this? I'm tryin to do that with tricky stuff like:

```
$i = explode('.', $attribute);
$i = $i[1];
$input = $validator->getData();
```

to get the iterator and test manually... but isn't the right way.

Here is the example:

```
public function boot()
    {
        Validator::extend('greater_than', function($attribute, $price_purchase, $price_sell, $validator)
        {
            $result = floatval($price_purchase) > floatval($price_sell);
             return $result;
        });
}

public function validateStore($params) {
    'products.*.selling_price'  => 'greater_than:products.*.purchase_price',
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Validator::extend('greater_than', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
{
    $wildCard = explode('.', $attribute);
    $wildCard = $wildCard[1];
    $compareAttribute = str_replace('*', $wildCard, $parameters[0]);
    $compareValue = array_get($validator->getData(), $compareAttribute);
    $result = floatval($value) > floatval($compareValue);
    return $result;
});
```

Obviously this solution is not an extensive 'greater than' validator and only works for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks so much dude! array_get is the way :)